# Unexpected Behavior After State Change in React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
    RenderImages = (): React.ReactElement => {
        let selected = this.state.results.filter(x=>this.state.selectedGroups.includes(x.domain))
        console.log(selected)
        return(
            <div className="results_wrapper">
                {selected.map((r,i)=>{
                    let openState = (this.state.selectedImage==i)?true:false;
                    return(
                        <RenderPanel panelType={PanelType.large} openState={openState} title={r.domain+'.TheCommonVein.net'} preview={(openIt)=>(
                            
                            <div className="result" onClick={openIt} style={{ boxShadow: theme.effects.elevation8}}>
                                <img src={r.url} />
                            </div>
                        )} content={(closeIt)=>(
                            <div className="panel_wrapper">
                                <div className="panel_content">{r.content}</div>
                                {this.RenderPostLink(r.domain,r.parent)}
                                <div onClick={()=>{
                                    closeIt();
                                    this.setState({selectedImage:2})
                                    console.log('wtfff'+this.state.selectedImage)
                                }
                            }>Next</div>
                                <img src={r.url} />
                            </div>
                        )}/>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

When I change the state of 'selectedImage', I expect the variable 'openState' to render differently within my map() function. But it does not do anything.

Console.log shows that the state did successfully change.

And what is even stranger, is if I run "this.setState({selectedImage:2})" within componentsDidMount(), then everything renders exactly as expected.

Why is this not responding to my state change?

### Update

I have tried setting openState in my component state variable, but this does not help either:

```
   RenderImages = (): React.ReactElement => {
        let selected = this.state.results.filter(x=>this.state.selectedGroups.includes(x.domain))
        console.log(selected)
        let html = selected.map((r,i)=>{
                    return(
                        <RenderPanel key={i} panelType={PanelType.large} openState={this.state.openState[i]} title={r.domain+'.TheCommonVein.net'} preview={(openIt)=>(
                            
                            <div className="result" onClick={openIt} style={{ boxShadow: theme.effects.elevation8}}>
                                <img src={r.url} />
                            </div>
                        )} content={(closeIt)=>(
                            <div className="panel_wrapper">
                                <div className="panel_content">{r.content}</div>
                                {this.RenderPostLink(r.domain,r.parent)}
                                <div onClick={()=>{
                                    closeIt();
                                    let openState = this.state.openState.map(()=>false)
                                    let index = i+1
                                    openState[index] = true;
                                    this.setState({openState:openState},()=>console.log(this.state.openState[i+1]))
                                }
                            }>Next</div>
                                <img src={r.url} />
                            </div>
                        )}/>
                    )
                })
        return(
            <div className="results_wrapper">
                {html}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

---

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bas-1v3p9?file=/src/Search.tsx

To test, just hit enter at the search box. Then click on 1 of 3 of the results. When you click 'Next', it should close the pane, and open the next one. That is what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Is this component actually a member of a class component?

Comment: Yes it is. I just didn't post the rest of it. If you need the code, I can.

Comment: I'll not attempt to debug it, but logging the new state after calling setState will not work as you want. setState is async, pass a callback to it as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @RodrigoAmaral I'm aware of that, but logging it is not a problem, I've already proved to myself that the state is being set.

Comment: getting `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.` after hitting enter in the `Search` component

Comment: Strange, we are looking at the same thing and I'm not getting that error. Try typing some random text?

Comment: panel.tsx is a folder in the codesandbox.

Comment: I've uploaded it again

Comment: @SevanGolnazarian I would appreciate if you can elaborate on your downvote at this point

Comment: I wouldn't downvote without an explanation. However, I suggest you edit the title to something along the lines of "Unexpected Behavior After State Change in React Component" also add typescript to the tags. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Spitz was on the right path with his answer, though didn't follow through to the full solution.

The issue you are having is that the panel's `useBoolean` doesn't update it's state based on the `openState` value passed down.

If you add the following code to panel.tsx, then everything will work as you described:

```
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        if(openState){
            openPanel()
        }else{
            dismissPanel();
        }
    },[openState, openPanel,dismissPanel])
```

What this is doing is setting up an effect to synchronize the `isOpen` state in the `RenderPanel` with the `openState` that's passed as a prop to the `RenderPanel`. That way while the panel controls itself for the most part, if the parent changes the openState, it'll update.

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dust-l5tpc?file=/src/panel.tsx)

Comment: Why does useBoolean not update its state? Is it because it is not being used inside a Component or is this just its behavior? THANK YOU for your brilliance

Comment: That's just its behavior. Looking at their docs, you can see that the parameter of the function is just the `initialState`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/react-hooks?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#useboolean-initialstate-

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you set openState in your map function, after it has already run.  I understand you think the function should rerender and then the loop will run once more, but I think you'll need to set openState in a function outside of render.

Comment: openState is dependent on "i", the enumeration value from the map function. I'm not sure if I can do that outside of it. Also, why does it behave correctly when I set state in componentsDidMount()?

Comment: Can you add openState to the state of the class and then setState({openState:true}) instead?  Instead of doing it in the ternary do it in the onClick function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even though you can access `this.state` from the component, which is a member of a class component, there's nothing that would make the component re-render. Making components inside other components is an anti-pattern and produces unexpected effects - as you've seen.

The solution here is to either move RenderImages into a separate component altogether and pass required data via props or context, or turn it into a normal function and call it as a function in the parent component's `render()`.

The latter would mean instead of `<RenderImages/>`, you'd do `this.RenderImages()`. And also since it's not a component anymore but just a function that returns JSX, I'd probably rename it to `renderImages`.

Comment: I currently already call it as a regular function in my render function. I call it like this: const images = this.RenderImages();

Comment: @Raven I see. Try giving `<RenderPanel>` a `key`.

Comment: sorry I'm still new to this - what is a key, and how do I give RenderPanel it?

Comment: See this part of React's documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: thank you. I tried that just now : `<RenderPanel key={i} ... ` where i is the enumerated value from map. It behaves the same way unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest trying to cut out things not related to the issue and make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Alternatively, if your entire class is not very large, please include it in your question so that it's possible to actually run the code in question.

Comment: I just posted a codesandbox example in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I tire to look at it again and again, but couldn't wrap my head around why it wasn't working with any clean approach.

That being said, I was able to make it work with a "hack", that is to explicitly call `openIt` method for `selectedImage` after rendering is completed.

```
RenderImages = (): React.ReactElement => {
  let selected = this.state.results.filter((x) =>
    this.state.selectedGroups.includes(x.domain)
  );

  return (
    <div className="results_wrapper">
      {selected.map((r, i) => {
        let openState = this.state.selectedImage === i ? true : false;
        return (
          <RenderPanel
            key={i}
            panelType={PanelType.medium}
            openState={openState}
            title={r.domain + ".TheCommonVein.net"}
            preview={(openIt) => {

              /* This is where I am making explicit call */
              if (openState) {
                setTimeout(() => openIt());
              }
              /* changes end */
    
              return (
                <div
                  className="result"
                  onClick={openIt}
                  style={{ boxShadow: theme.effects.elevation8 }}
                >
                  <img src={r.url} />
                </div>
              );
            }}
            content={(closeIt) => (
              <div className="panel_wrapper">
                <div className="panel_content">{r.content}</div>
                {this.RenderPostLink(r.domain, r.parent)}
                <div
                  onClick={() => {
                    closeIt();
                    this.setState({
                      selectedImage: i + 1
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  [Next>>]
                </div>
                <img src={r.url} />
              </div>
            )}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

take a look at [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-robinson-007l4).